# Problem with running my python code in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to run my code, it shows this on my output
/bin/sh: python: command not found
What should I do?

I tried to change the interpreter by installing python but it is still not working.
Even my IDlE is having a problem starting (sub-process didn't make a connection or startup failure)
I'm wondering if both of them are related somehow
I'm a newbie to all of this

Comment: Did you try a tutorial, like https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial ? Do that first. If it doesn't work, please show us what you did, and what errors you get.